# Can anyone tell me why I am not getting cookies in front end

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, backend

I am using Node js and react. I am new to the web development. Everythings works perfectly in localhost but when I deploy my backend and front end on render, cookies wont get send to the front end after login. I have deployed backend on web server and front end on static web.

Here is my code in node js on login

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    const q = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?'

    db.query(q, [req.body.username],(err, data)=>{
        if(err) return res.json({Error:"Something's wrong on server side"})
        
        if(data.length>0){
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, data[0].password,(err, result)=>{
                if(err) return res.json("Something wrong in server side")
                if(result===true)  {
                    const user = {id:data[0].id, username:data[0].username, userimg:data[0].userimg};
                    const accesstoken = createTokens(user)
                    res.cookie('token', accesstoken,{
                        httpOnly:true
                    }).json({getdata:result,userdata:user})}

                else{ return res.json({Error:`Password didn't match`})}
            })        
        }
        else{
            return res.json({Error:"User doesn't exist"})
        }  
    }) 
})
```

When user logs in, cookies need to be set on front end as token. It works well in local host development mode but not on production mode. I have used postman on my backend server. It works perfectly, even cookies get send in postman after login but not in my front end website.

[image: Post man screenshot]

Comment: If your frontend uses a different domain than the backend (`.onrender.com`), the cookies will count as [tag:third-party-cookies] and be blocked by many browsers.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen How do you fix it??

Comment: You can use your Node.js server as a proxy to `.onrender.com`. Search for "proxy requests" on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Another workaround can be returning the access token as a custom header or body response in that way you wouldn't have to use a cookie.